# Possible to make border-radius equal to half the total height without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and the mockup calls for the left and right ends of a certain type of element to each be half-circles. Since the elements will be different heights depending on how much text is in them, I know that means I somehow need to make their border-radii be equal to half the total height of the element. Is this possible without using JS?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Definitely – just set the `border-radius` to a large size!

```css
#some-element {
    border-radius: 9999px;
}
```

It will top out at the maximum size that allows circular corners. If your element is taller than it is wide, though, keep in mind that you can’t have both sides be half-circles without widening the element.

Comment: I believe this answer is closer to what OP was asking for.

Comment: Wow, thank you, would have never come to this on my own

Comment: Only downside to this is it can make any animations look whiplashy, since you're only seeing the tail end or beginning of the range from `9999px` to whatever. (Haven't found a better solution myself though yet—no CSS unit for "percent of shortest/longest side of parent" yet)